# Generate List for label with barcode printing from tablem with number quantity of rows

Tags: oracle

I try to generate list of products for printing labels, but all of my attempt fail (with connect by level)!

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE LABELS
(
 PRODUCT    VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
  Q_ROWS     NUMBER
);
```

Information in the table:

```
INSERT INTO LABELS (PRODUCT, Q_ROWS) VALUES('D', 3);
INSERT INTO LABELS (PRODUCT, Q_ROWS) VALUES('A', 1);
INSERT INTO LABELS (PRODUCT, Q_ROWS) VALUES('C', 4);
INSERT INTO LABELS (PRODUCT, Q_ROWS) VALUES('B', 2);
```

Expected Result in a oracle select

```
PRODUCT
A       
B
B
C
C
C
C
D
D
D
```

Results: (1 row for A, 2 rows for B, 4 rows to C and 3 rows to D)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEVEL` to get a "table" that counts from `1` to the maximum number of rows:

```
SELECT LEVEL AS LabelNum
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(Q_Rows) FROM Labels)
```

This will give you the following table:

```
LabelNum
--------
       1
       2
       3
       4
```

Next, join this to your `LABELS` table where `LabelNum <= Q_Rows`. Here's the whole query:

```
WITH Mult AS (
  SELECT LEVEL AS LabelNum
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(Q_Rows) FROM Labels)
)
SELECT Product
FROM Labels
INNER JOIN Mult ON LabelNum <= Q_Rows
ORDER BY Product, LabelNum
```

There's a working SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc46d/3).

Finally, good job including the create/populate scripts :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using [model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2172805) clause:

```
select product
  from labels
model
partition by (product)
dimension by (1 as indx)
measures(q_rows)
rules(
  q_rows[for indx from 1 to q_rows[1] increment 1] = q_rows[1] 
)
order by product
```

result:

```
PRODUCT
----------
A
B
B
C
C
C
C
D
D
D
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc46d/12)

Comment: Thanks, other way very usefull ;)